# Fit a rectangle around a string on an Android Canvas

Tags: java, android, graphics, android-canvas

So I use **Canvas.drawText** to draw some string on a **Canvas**. The issue is that I want to draw a rectangle before it so that the text appears centred onto the rectangle. But I hit a real problem. The supplied **x** and **y** coordinates to **drawText** actually are not of the "*top left*" corner of the real text, but rather on the line where the characters begin. There is a method **Paint.getTextBounds** which returns a rectangle "with implied origin" at *(0,0)* of the text that would be drawn. The issue is that the origin is at *(0,0)*. The width and the height of that box are correct but I don't know how to place its top left corner at the top left corner of the string that is drawn on the canvas. I guess I should use **FontMetrics**, but since a lot of the values **FontMetrics** returns are undocumented I'm not really sure how to use them for my purpose.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ended up doing

```
FontMetrics fm = new FontMetrics();
paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
paint.getFontMetrics(fm);
canvas.drawText(text, x, y + -(fm.ascent + fm.descent) / 2, paint);
```

Which actually draws the text centered at **x**, **y**. Before that I draw a rectangle centered at **x**, **y** with width **paint.measureText(*text*)**

Comment: I've struggled to draw text that center in a rectangle for a while. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

try drawing rectangle using

`canvas.drawRect(x, y - Paint.GetTextSize(), x + Paint.measureText("text"), y, Paint);`

Comment: I think this would work, though I ended up doing another thing that also worked for me so now I can't try it to see whether this method works. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: what is this x and y?

Comment: In this context, x and y are where OP is drawing text, answer is to draw a box around this text.

Comment: any soluction to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176321/canvas-drawtext-positioning

Answer (score 0):

rectangle around the text

th is the gap between the rectangle and the text

textStart - the beginning point of the text (PointF)

```
    val textRect = Rect().also {
        paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length, it)
        it.offsetTo(
        when(paint.textAlign){
            Paint.Align.RIGHT -> {
                (textStart.x - it.width()).toInt()
            }
            
            Paint.Align.CENTER -> {
               (textStart.x - it.width()/2f).toInt()
            }
            else -> {
               textStart.x.toInt()
           }
    }, textStart.y.toInt() - it.height())
    }.toRectF().also{it.inset(-th, -th)}
  canvas.drawRect(textRect, paint)
```