# Canvas drawtext positioning

Tags: android, android-canvas, drawtext

I am creating a drawing tool, where user add text to image. While making the text draw to bitmap via canvas position is not being set properly.

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setTypeface(tf);
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);

        paint.setTextSize(30);



int xPos = layoutTextViewContainer.getLeft();
        int yPos = layoutTextViewContainer.getTop();
        canvas.drawText(text, xPos, yPos, paint);
```

**Paint**

```
Rect textRect = new Rect();
        paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textRect);
        textRect.offset(0, -textRect.top);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
```

layoutTextViewContainer holds the edit text.
Screen shot for more clarification.
Black text is written and Red text is preview of embed in image[image]

Comment: SO your problem is your calculation of the x and y position.  We'd need you to post that.  By the way, the x and y positions are the bottom left of the baseline of the text, so being off in the y is likely the you assuming it was upper left.

Comment: I am getting the top and left position of Red box and then passing it to drawText

Comment: more info on paint added

Comment: You need to post the code where you set xpos and ypos.  Its impossible to debug without it

Comment: xPos and YPos are provided above its the top and left of container layout

Answer (score 2):

Got the solution. the values should be pixel independent 
convert xPos and yPos as below before passing to drawText

```
 xPos = (int) (xPos / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    yPos = (int) (yPos / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its even better to use Drawing cache and save that to any file location. 
In this case we dont have to much bother about positioning.
Wrap all in one layout and get the

```
 view.getDrawingCache()
```